# How to fill NA in PySpark like in Pandas

Tags: pyspark, replace, null

I want to replace `NA` values in PySpark, and basically I can

```
df.na.fill(0) #it works
```

BUT, I want to replace these values enduringly, it means like using `INPLACE` in pandas.

When I check nulls after executing code belowe, there is no changes at all.

```
df.select([count(when(isnan(c) | col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show() #I use this code to check null in data set
```

Do you know how to entirely replace `NA` in PySpark? I want to achieve the same effect like with `inplace` in pandas (**permanently replaced values**).

I've used this code to repalce values:

```
df.na.fill(0)
```

and I've used code below to check the effect

```
df.select([count(when(isnan(c) | col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
```

Unfornutnatelly I can only display new replaced values without permanently replaced nulls in my data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fill the null value in spark, you can just use the `.fillna()`, which is

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```

You can check this docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna.html. However, in spark dataframe, if your filling value is not same as the column data type, even you use `.fillna()`, the column value will still be null.

Comment: Yes! Thx, issue was non compliance of data types (column was a STRING and I tried to fill null values with 0)